# How to crop a photo using a (non-square) cookie cutter template?

Tags: xcode, swift3, crop

For example: A user takes a picture of a nice car and then want to be able to crop it into a heart shape. I want them to be able to look at the photo through a heart template, scroll what part of the car image they want into the heart slot. This then only saves what is inside of the heart, making the (partial, cropped) image heart shaped.

Not exactly sure how to piece it all together though or if its possible to crop with irregular shapes. Anyone have any knowledge on this? And with recent Swift 3 syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your cookie cutter is what is referred to as a mask image.  White parts of the mask are kept; black parts are cut out.

```
  func masked(image:UIImage, mask:(UIImage))->UIImage?{
      guard let cgImage = image.cgImage, let cgMask = mask.cgImage else {
          return nil
      }
      UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(image.size)
      guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else {
          return nil
      }
      let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: image.size.width, height: image.size.height)
      context.clip(to: rect, mask: cgMask)
      context.draw(cgImage, in: rect)
      return UIImage(cgImage: context.makeImage()!)
  }
```

Comment: Thank you and much appreciated for the clarification!